# node.js / v8 Reading Large Files Into Memory

Tags: node.js, v8

## Question

How can you read files > 1.1 GB into memory under node.js?

### Example

I'm trying to use topojson under node.js to convert > 1.1 GB GeoJSON files to TopoJSON format.

```
$ topojson -o outfile.json larger_than_one_point_one_GB_input_file.json
```

(the above has worked for files up to 517 MB)

Results in the following error

```
buffer.js:242
this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
                    ^
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:242:21)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:200:14)
    at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson:61:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson:60:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

### What I've Tried so Far

- Extensive searching
- Command line memory settings

  - `--max-stack-size=2147000000`
  - `--max_executable_size=2000`
  - `--max_new_space_size=2097152`
  - `--max_old_space_size=2097152`
- Custom compile most recent v8 version into custom node.js install

  - They [appear to have removed](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=13298) this memory limit (if I'm correct, I may not be)
  - This was not successful

### Versions

- node.js: v0.8.15
- v8: 3.11.10.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because topojson uses [`fs.readFileSync`](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/bin/topojson#L61) to read the entire file. What that does is open a buffer of size (length of file), then fill it up. But node buffers [have a maximum size](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_buffer.h#L69) of `0x3FFFFFFF` bytes, or `1GB - 1 byte`. So you get that exception.

Solution? Open the topojson source and replace readFileSync with streaming methods which wouldn't read the entire file as one block. Or if you're feeling really hackish, maybe recompile node with a larger `kMaxLength` constant...

Comment: Fascinating. I'll try replacing `readFileSync` with a streaming method. If it works, I'll gladly mark your answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck - I don't know how easy this will be since you may have to change some other things as well, like the `JSON.stringify` call later on - that would probably fail as well with the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been successful so far. Probably because my javascript and node.js fu are weak. I read the file as a stream, but can't write it to memory (same issue). There's no point writing back to disk. Perhaps some intelligent way of splitting it across multiple buffers...

Comment: You could try recompiling Node for this specific one-time operation. Like I said, it's hacky, but for a one-time run should work. The only change you'd have to make is the `kMaxLength` constant. From my cursory glance it looks like everything else should _just work_.

Comment: Oh, and some of the constants in deps/v8/src/objects.h might need to change too.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your advice and input here. I'll admit, I've hit my skill limit on this after several concerted attempts. If I make a breakthrough, I'll update this post! Thanks again.